# Что такое плюсик перед функцией в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, браузер, типы-данных, fetch

Наткнулся на такую строчку в одной статье по JavaScript:

```
const contentLength = +response.headers.get('Content-Length');
```

Что такое плюсик? Приведение типов? Можно заменить на:

```
const contentLength = Number(response.headers.get('Content-Length'));
```

Та статья: http://webdiz.com.ua/fetch-khod-zagruzki/

Comment: за оформление вопроса вам плюсик )))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

да, это Приведение любых типов в числовые